# Render CSS in Django

Tags: html, css, django, rendering, stylesheet

I am trying to get the CSS sheet to load on my development computer. It is in the media directory as `media/base.css`. In my `base/base.html` template, I have:

```
<link href="media/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I found [this page](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/), but that didn't fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if media/ is your project media directory, then in the template use

```
<link href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

this is considering you have passed RequestContext to your template, 
ex:

```
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                              my_data_dictionary,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You will also need to have static urls served when running on the localdev server. 
Include this in your urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
                            url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:],
                                'django.views.static.serve',
                                {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True})
                            )
```