# html site cant find css although I tried every possible way that has been suggested on Stackoverflow

Tags: python, html, css

The problem I have is that I have a html site which cant find the css I am linking.
The html site is opened via flask in my local host which works but I get an error that says that the css file cant be found. If is click on my html file and open it normally, the css works, but via flask not.

I also tried multiple folder structures:

1)
main.py

templates(folder)

-index.html

static(folder)

-main.css

2. current structure:
   main.py

templates(folder)

-index.html

-main.css

The way I link to my main css with folder structure 2:

`<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

I have also tried al variations from this answere but none of them work.

[HTML not loading CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992546/html-not-loading-css/23992979)

[image: Main.py]

[[image: html filecss file]

Comment: What is `href=href=`? Typo?

Comment: I think you should refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22260791/1831502

Comment: I fixex href=href it was just here in this question not in my real code

Comment: I also tried the link you have sent. It does not work either

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/website/how-to-link-a-stylesheet-css-file-to-your-html-file

You could also try the   tag

If it is in a folder and they are **Both** in the same folder you should try:

and you should put this in the header

---

Here is an example:

```
 **HTML:**

<!Doctype HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="screen"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test">
      <p> This is an example paragraph </p>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>

 **CSS**

#test {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

---

Try ./main.css or /main.css or .main.css

Comment: The problem is that the css it not working when I open it with flask. Otherwise it works

Comment: I haven't tried to use flask before

Comment: Could you try to use the style tag?

Comment: Style does not work either properly. Just a few lines work. Pls send me an example

Comment: I solved it! I refreshed my broser cache with ctrl+F5 and now everything works fine!!!