# How to properly load js script into html/djangoTemplate?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, queryselector

Using Django templates, I'm trying to add a countdown in javascript. Putting the script explicitly in HTML does work but it doesn't when loaded. I think I'm close but I can't figure out what is missing :/.

Here is a working piece of code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
</head>

<body>
{% if remaining_time %}
    <script>
        function startTimer(duration, display) {
            var timer = duration;
            var end = setInterval(function () {
                minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
                seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

                if (--timer < 0) {
                    clearInterval(end);
                    document.form_submit_answer.submit()
                }
            }, 1000);
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            var allowed_time_seconds = "{{remaining_time | safe}}",
                display = document.querySelector('#time');
            startTimer(allowed_time_seconds, display);
        };
    </script>
{% endif %}

    {{ current_question.title }}
    <div>
        <form name="form_submit_answer" action="{% url 'assignment_completion' token current_question_num %}"
            method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <div>
                {% if next_question %}
                <input type="submit" value="Send your answer and go to the next question">
                {% else %}
                <input type="submit" value="Send your answer and end the assignment">
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>
        TOKEN : {{ token }}
    </div>

    {% if remaining_time %}
    <div>Time remaining : <span id="time">{{initial_remaining_time}}</span></div>
    {% endif %}
</body>

</html>
```

But When I remove the script from the HTML and I put it in `/static/js/timer.js` then make the import in `<head>`, it doesn't work anymore, the `initial_remaining_time` is displayed but it is not decremented each second.

Here is my piece of code which is not working :

```
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% if remaining_time %}
    <script src="{ % static 'js/timer.js' % }"></script>
    {% endif %}
</head>
```

Expected result : Display of the initial time then decrement until 0, at 0, send the form !

In practice when putting timer.js in /static/js/timer.js, only the initial time is displayed and then nothing happens as if the javascript was never loaded and played.

Traceback :
(nkFjLIDrya1BrWd2bqYnq7TC5bpGCRGW3HcDXa6cqYI is a token)

```
[18/Jul/2019 11:12:32] "GET /nkFjLIDrya1BrWd2bqYnq7TC5bpGCRGW3HcDXa6cqYI/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 1017
Not Found: /nkFjLIDrya1BrWd2bqYnq7TC5bpGCRGW3HcDXa6cqYI/{ % static 'js/timer.js' % }
[18/Jul/2019 11:12:32] "GET /nkFjLIDrya1BrWd2bqYnq7TC5bpGCRGW3HcDXa6cqYI/%7B%20%%20static%20'js/timer.js'%20%%20%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 2617
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: `<script src="{% static 'yourAppName/path/to/app.js' %}">`

If it keeps telling you that it can't find that specific file, then you probably haven't correctly configured your settings.py to know where your static directory should be.

Comment: Thank you, it's working, I forgot about :

`STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), ) ` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313314/django-how-to-include-javascript-in-template)  

Also I had to define a global variable :  

```
    <script>
        var remaining_time_js = "{{ remaining_time | safe}}";
    </script>
```  

and use it inside timer.js :  

```
window.onload = function () {
    var allowed_time_seconds = remaining_time_js,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(allowed_time_seconds, display);
};
```