# what am i doing wrong? CSS files don't work in Django project

Tags: python, css, django, web

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Japan</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
```

what must i do to work css files in django project?

Comment: everything is ok

Comment: but still doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

You need the add the static URL :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: Check this maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145994/a-simple-example-of-django-and-css